# Translate message from tabledrag.js

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I try to translate the message that is used in the following JavaScript code.

```
Drupal.t('Changes made in this table will not be saved until the form is submitted.')
```

I use the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module; I tried also translation using settings.php. None of the methods work.

Does anybody have an idea on how to translate the sentence? I do not want to use big modules like localize.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal loaded only the needed strings on every page which we are included. 
Those strings are added in javascript itself.

I think this is fixed by across the script files before they are actually added to the page.

So, you should be able to translate that string into the translate interface.

For more help, You can see this link,

https://www.drupal.org/node/323109

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to translate the string without localize module. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I think you need to use localize module without this you can not do translation.

Comment: Unless you use localize or internationalization modules you can not translate any string, though it is included in the t() function.